# why react-youtube auto not working reactjs

Tags: reactjs

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import YouTube from 'react-youtube';

const Header = () => {
    const opts = {
        height: '410',
        width: '510',
        playerVars: {
            autoplay: 1,
        },
    };

    const onReady = (event) => {
        event.target.playVideoAt(10)
    }
    return (
        <header className="header">
            <YouTube videoId="GzJJcLN4Jmo" allow="autoplay" opts={opts} autoplay onReady={onReady} />
            <div className='container'>
                <ul>
                    <li>Home</li>
                    <li>About me</li>
                    <li>Contact</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </header>

    );
}
export default Header;
```

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by "not working"? What do you expect to happen, and what happens instead? (Please add these to your question)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.